# Undefined is not a function: Module export

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a little module export. I require that the var `myFunc() = function()...` is intact, the code I am trying to make module is pretty complicated.

Here is the file `js/test.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    app: function () {
        var myFunc = function (arg) {
            return 'working '+arg;
        }
    }
};
```

Run it with:

```
var test = require('./js/test.js');
console.log(test.app.myFunc('now'));
```

Here is the error:

```
test.app.myFunc();
         ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Okay. What is `app`? I mean what does it have?

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm trying to invoke `myFunc()` somehow. `app` is just a random name I took.

Comment: App is a function, you need to invoke it.

Comment: `app` is actually a function. And you have another function defined inside `app` function. So, the inner function will not even be created unless the `app` is executed. Since it is local to the `app` function, it can only be accessed within the `app` function only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `myFunc` is a local variable of the function `app`, not a member, so it isn't available as `app.myFunc` (You can't access a function's local members in this way. Or at all, for that matter). If module.exports.app absolutely *must* be a function, and not, say, an object, you can do this:

```
module.exports = {
    app: function() {
    }
};
module.exports.app.myFunc = function(arg) {
    return 'working '+arg;
};
```

However, it would be much saner for `app` to simply be a literal object:

```
module.exports = {
    app: {
        myFunc: function(arg) {
            return 'working '+arg;
        }
    }
};
```

Alternately, if you need `myFunc` to depend on variables internal to `app` (Although that shouldn't be necessary, since modules already imply encapsulation):

```
module.exports = {
    app: (function() {
        var _internal = 'working ';
        return {
            myFunc: function(arg) {
                return _internal+arg;
            }
        };
    })()
};
```

If you need `myFunc` to depend on parameters passed to `app`:

```
module.exports = {
    app: (function(passed) {
        return {
            myFunc: function(arg) {
                return passed+arg;
            }
        };
    })()
};
```

And then you use it as

```
var test = require('./js/test.js');
console.log(test.app('working ').myFunc('now'));
```

That's all the options I can think of. If this still doesn't answer your question, it would help if you explain what you're trying to accomplish a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this to work:

```
module.exports = {
    app: {
        myFunc : function () {
            console.log('working');
        }
    }
};
```

And then you will can run it with this:

```
var test = require('./js/test.js');
test.app.myFunc();
```

Comment: Ok I apologize, I have updated the question to show a better example now!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the point of complicating the code so much is, but nevertheless if you want to complicate it furthermore you can do this

```
module.exports = {
    app: (function () {
        var myFunc = function (arg) {
            return 'working '+arg;
        }

        return {myFunc: myFunc}
    }())
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to make an existing javascript file module. And it insists on using `var myFunc()`, don't get me wrong, if I wrote it I would do it correct from the beginning, but the author has just made it complicated.

Comment: @KarlMorrison So why is not the other answer working for you?

Comment: Currently implementing it as we speak!